# Lower bound for the largest number of triangles with a common edge

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

While self-learning an introductory graph theorey course, I ran into below after-class exercise following Mantel's theorem:

> Exercise 1.1.9*. Prove that every $n$-vertex graph with at least $\left\lfloor n^{2} / 4\right\rfloor+1$ edges contains some edge in at least $(1 / 6-o(1)) n$ triangles, and that this constant $1 / 6$ is best possible.

---

Although I can't prove it, I did find it used and refered by numerous papers, tracing a stronger result in [[EFR]](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271536/1-s2.0-S0012365X00X02920/1-s2.0-0012365X92905865/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEIP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDgGGMKcdAKOGLKa%2F9681CDbqu7jHvT3ede5GNfLTTGpgIhANM7%2FQJBoO88o9x7HhnEm07EnxbJVazUkQRMVsRXOZ4vKoMECLv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBBoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgxxPzTWaQbRr9q9Xzwq1wPJdk9mj5VxxVDiCavpnq3pjqZx%2BO01RSGM2kxO444k7tL3o5STLP7pH27SbRF5Syfhv%2BkUlTdKdGkXhG0dq2SmvMGkYX0qgvGb%2FLnFPxESA%2FjUBfHX4Hl3nDvMxHFsvnNIEwzWBhA0GkCTFFy4vMPKXekJMUnPVOIDYCqdbOKoKsGMRyATSMojxwYVsvMZzEaK%2FV8Yp%2FBYUU12UWQq5mG985JzmabTdjTPIAf5lmtMjBcNhTsBmJa4VyfIHiOTSEOVskA0OrUkFnNIWs0pZa4NmuVOFNXW6WXl8lEdLnWEku8ss6SGz27reUHJAPl3KPWdvxdugFZSKDm4pvaso71JvCxMchZknrH1pdab1gLYUgHj1pLXm4y%2FOlDgf8GqqEdb3XBrYHplacmdqT1YZQ1sIJqVJ6L33eX6YBosNUGJbn2P%2FjYyBQnQizGa0WXiYQM4qHLKWSQKW8i8M2GN%2Fpae9ThQBkpEgRixLspTZgwT59SWbrqjzrD46smxawUQHgLehgME2Iu0vqcQ25HUNs3W4PV3qWryaOq6%2FyDLo12fW3lN%2Fn56AaBuyocdGKhyVeLBVHbChylx2faON1Vw7UVZu3XKRKmEqG9riCz7JZ3QNilPau6VW0owy7v%2BjwY6pAF83gkTKibid%2FN%2FkIUXlxaxt2JLCwmTx1cYs4F89mtBJa9nyuQWrdJpy%2FGme9GZoYIDa6Kx9rkecy1gx%2F1LCvN%2FoNKxcVo8kNAAHDrf9zvBac8FcYHHSv4QlmCVaQjDLXRS5H4rLyiQ28rWT42Q%2FEA4ixGbtKt8sN7eejQkcbHm8InN0%2Fj8Cz2r6EtkgM0HaIXy4oE7VsWfOAqGDD00Hi4e0FVFhA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220206T103416Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYUF36IOFU%2F20220206%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0e10868d227f77adf6af457e7f345f5cb2a165c5de2431e64efc7b77ffd2963b&hash=42fd31c8d067163447d82b4f6782a6fd09db0e6b5050067e8cc1bec595789fdf&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0012365X92905865&tid=spdf-d25949bd-8b77-43d5-b489-52364b755a1c&sid=9b09a33a34d90942a5489ee74ad89af2357agxrqa&type=client&ua=500a5a5500595f015857&rr=6d93b99d985ded7b):

> Lemma 4 (Edwards). Every graph with $n$ vertices and $\left\lfloor n^{2} / 4\right\rfloor+1$ edges contains an edge common to at least $n / 6$ triangles.
> Note. This result was conjectured by Bollobás and Erdós in [1]. To see that this is essentially best possible, consider the graph of order $n=6 k$ whose vertices are partitioned into six independent sets $X(r, c)(r=1,2, c=1,2,3)$ with cardinalities
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &|X(2,1)|=|X(2,3)|=k-1, \quad|X(1,3)|=|X(2,2)|=k, \\
> &|X(1,1)|=|X(1,2)|=k+1 .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Join distinct sets $X(r, c)$ and $X\left(r^{\prime}, c^{\prime}\right)$ completely if either $r=r^{\prime}$ or $c=c^{\prime} .$ This gives a graph with $9 k^{2}+1=n^{2} / 4+1$ edges in which every edge is on at most $k+1$ triangles. To the knowledge of the authors, the proof of Lemma 4 has never been published. In his unpublished manuscript, Edwards proves a stronger result. Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges and let $f_{3}(G)$ denote the largest integer such that $G$ contains $f_{3}(G)$ triangles with a common edge. Set
> $$
> c_{v}^{2}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-d_{i} / \bar{d}\right)^{2}
> $$
> where $d_{1}, d_{2}, \ldots, d_{n}$ are the degrees of the vertices of $G$ and $\bar{d}=2 m / n$ is the average degree. Edwards proves that if $m \geqslant n^{2} /\left(4\left(1+c_{v}^{2}\right)\right)$ and $G$ is not bipartite, then
> $$
> f_{3}(G) \geqslant \frac{2 m}{n}\left(1+c_{v}^{2}\right)-\frac{n}{3}=\frac{1}{2 m} \sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{i}^{2}-\frac{n}{3} .
> $$
> As an immediate corollary, if $m>\left\lfloor n^{2} / 4\right\rfloor$ then
> $$
> f_{3}(G) \geqslant \frac{2 m}{n}-\frac{n}{3} .
> $$
> In particular, setting $\left.m=\rceil n^{2} / 4\right\rfloor+1$ we have the result quoted in Lemma $4 .$

I also find that the same result was independently proved in this article: N. Khadžiivanov and V. Nikiforov, Solution of a problem of P. Erdős about the maximum number of triangles with a common edge in a graph, $C .$ R. Acad. Bulgare Sci. $\mathbf{3 2}(1979)$ $1315-1318 .$ Although I couldn't find it either, and it's likely to be in Russian.

I wish someone can help me with this exercise, hopefully the above information would be of help to you.

---

I find a proof for the stronger result with no $o(1)$ term in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405080, but I am still looking forward to explanation for Erdos's original proof.

Comment: With the $o(1)$ slack, this was definitely known to Erdős (see Lemma 2 of https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1962-09.pdf)

Comment: @md5 I have some trouble computing the best value of c2 in the proof of the Lemma 2. My straight computation from inequality (2) gives $c_2n$'s upper bound $\frac{n}6−\frac{r}4+\frac1{2}$, where the middle term don't seems to be O(1) , as the paper claimed. Could you please take a look at this?

Comment: Hi! I am actually interested in this question. I was wondering did you solve it eventually?

Comment: @ZFR I finally found a proof for the stronger result (without the $o(1)$ term) in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405080

Comment: I was wondering can you upload the proof? It is a corollary of the long theorem and the proof is not short!